# Удалить div по условию его содержимого

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть несколько div

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

Как я могу удалить только  `<div>c</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью jQuery-селектора `:contains`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('div:contains("c")').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

Comment: @zkolya, Пожалуйста, правда спасибо принято отмерять репутацией. И, если ответ вас удовлетворил, примите его.